# sprintf() return fixed point number PHP

Tags: php, string-formatting

In PHP, can i return a fixed point value using sprintf or similar command like vsprintf?

```
echo sprintf("text formatting goes here",3.14159265359); // 3.14
```

**Only variable here should be the formatting string, the input should be irelevant**

Comment: You can also use `round(3.14159265359, 2);` function.

Comment: the input in this function could be anything, i need it as flexible as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [sprintf documentation](https://www.php.net/sprintf).

```
sprintf("%.2f", 3.1415);
```